# krajee fileupload plugin DELETE URL response

Tags: javascript, file-upload

what kind of json should i return, if i want to enable user to delete *just* uploaded image. That red garbage-can button does not send any requests, just deletes image from a view, not from a server.
I look at this [manual](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#ajax-async)

i respond on each upload now like this:

```
$p = [
'error' => '',
'initialPreviewConfig' => [
    [
    'url' => 'http://localhost/avatar/delete', // server delete action
    'key' => $_POST['file_id'],
    'extra' => ['id' => $_POST['file_id']]
    ]
]
]
```

ive tried varios options..

Answer (score 2):

i managed it with callbacks *filesuccessremove* & *fileuploaded*, there might be cleaner way. This api is complex, but really good.

```
    $("#fileuploader").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: 'uplurl',
        allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg'],
        maxFileSize: 800000,
        maxFilesNum: 10,
        language: 'pl',
    })
    .on('fileuploaded', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
            $('div.file-preview-thumbnails #'+previewId).attr('server_id',data.response.server_id)
            })
    .on('filesuccessremove', function(event, id) {
            event.preventDefault();
            dp = $('div.file-preview-thumbnails #'+id).attr('server_id')
            $.post('deletefilesurl', {'server_id':dp})
            .done(function(r){
                    if(r=='ok'){
                            $('#'+id).fadeOut(300, function(){$(this).remove()})
                    }else{
                    $('#'+id).addClass('btn-danger').find('.file-actions').html(r)
                    }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                    $('#'+id).addClass('btn-danger').find('.file-actions').html('nothing deleted')
            })

            return false
    });
```

code indentation might not be propper here, the idea, was just to to store stored image servers id in html-data attribute, on file uploaded, from a responce. And do a post on filesuccessremove event.
**note evet.preventdDefault must be used with conjunction return false from callback** to prevent thumbnail removal, and remove it manually as needed, if process was ok

fom php I just return this

```
return  [
    'error' => '',
    'server_id' => $i, //last db insert id
];
```